# In cmake, how can I make a target depend on another target?

Tags: dependencies, cmake, target

For example, I have library target A, and library target B depends on A.

Instead of adding A's source files to B's source file list, I just want B to depend on target A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need *just* the dependency (ordering), you can use `add_dependencies(B A)`.

However, your question suggests you actually want to link `B` against `A`. In that case, do `target_link_librairies(B A)`.

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble finding this in the docs because I wasn't sure what terminology to use.